# authentication in microservice, login problem

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, microservices

I create a few microservices as my student work. I created 2 microservices, they run, no errors. They easily register to Eureka Server. Fine, but when I go to localhost:8080 or other I see login page. Standard login (sa, empty) doesn't work.

When I changed in properties to other login/pass - it doesn't work. I tried to switch of, no result. I tried with WebSecurityConfig to switch off authentication

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()); // 

        return http.build();
```

No result. I still see login page. Actually, I don't need this authentication at all (it is only student work), but I can not use postman.

AME="Linux Mint" VERSION="21.1 (Vera)"

Spring-boot-starter-parent <version>3.1.5

spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4

IntelliJ U

<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the spring security as dependency in your pom file?
If you do not need it, you can just remove it. Or you can simply switch off the security at all `security.ignored=/**`

Comment: //you can simply switch off the security at all security.ignored=/**

in properties?

Comment: Yes, but if you are using spring boot 2 or above do the following instead: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

Comment: I did i. Still "Please sign in" and invalis credentials

Comment: I did i. Still "Please sign in" and invalid credentials
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.server.DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint@6d8f8506
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$HttpBasicSpec$$Lambda$973/0x00007ff15c775408@3519aaf7

Comment: DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint@1539c452
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0af162d6-5] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [0af162d6-5, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8087 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:54432] Last HTTP response frame

Comment: DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [0af162d6-5, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8087 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:54432] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [0af162d6-5, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8087 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:54432] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
DEBUG 11633 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations : [0af162d6-5, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8087 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:54432] Last HTTP packetwassent, terminatingthechannel

Comment: Could you please share your new configuration class?

Comment: # Ehcache Configuration
spring.cache.ehcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml

# Logging Configuration
logging.level.root=debug
logging.file.name=logs/myapp.log

# Server Configuration
server.port=9000

# Database Configuration for H2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: # Eureka Client Configuration
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.application.name=product-service
I used  
# Eureka Client Configuration
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.application.name=product-service

Comment: I used this http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll(); but it didnt work